# Does svn:needs-lock substitute lock?

Tags: svn, cornerstone

I'm using Cornerstone as SVN client and trying to use lock facility.

The idea is to let team members know that they can't edit particular file.

I read about locks on the product website, however, read-only property is set when svn:needs-lock is set no matter of lock state.

I was expecting the file to become read-only when the property is set to yes AND lock is set.

Please confirm that svn:needs-lock is substituting lock and in order to lock file with read-only attribute I ONLY have to set svn:needs-lock.

Answer (score 0):

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.locking.html

`svn lock` makes the file writable for you, while making it impossible for other users to lock it, while `svn unlock` makes it read-only once more and allows other users to lock it. It seems counterintuitive, but it's patterned after the "locks" and mutex jargon used in concurrent programming, where "locking" a resource means that only the active thread has access to it, and other threads have to wait until it is unlocked to use the resource.